# EFCache with multiple projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching

i have a solution with multiple projects like WCF, Console and Website. i am using entity framework and one dbcontext for all of them. 
I am trying to use EFCache as second level cache for entity framework. the problem is when i insert a new record from one of that projects others can't reload newly added data after change. 
for example i add a new record via WCF service into my database and when i try to load data from website the newly added data don't load and website has its efcache.

please help me...

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Dal component is running on a server shared by all the client UI's then you might have a similar issue I had.

I added the suggested code to my DbConfiguration startup method in my Dal project and then implemented just one of my specific Dal methods to use the cache.

```
//Add 2nd level cache support
var transactionHandler = new CacheTransactionHandler(new InMemoryCache());
AddInterceptor(transactionHandler);

var cachingPolicy = new CachingPolicy();
    Loaded +=
      (sender, args) => args.ReplaceService<DbProviderServices>(
         (s, _) => new CachingProviderServices(s, transactionHandler,
                  cachingPolicy));
```

I was maintaining a recently viewed record list and noticed that records I was viewing were not being remembered.  Debugging it seemed to run the EF query but it wasn't fetching all the records.  There was nothing showing in SQL profiler so that's when I realised it was caching much more than I intended.

Anyhow, I removed the above code from my DbConfiguration and just used the EFCache.InMemoryCache local in the Dals I wanted caching support.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or you might want to exclude some entities from caching or define the policy as described in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885939/exclude-certain-entities-from-second-level-caching